# Throttling settings for a new Graph API endpoint

Tags: powerbi, throttling

Power BI (1st party) service will integrate with usageRigths graph API beta endpoint:
GET /users/{userId}/usageRights.

The API calls will use the existing permissions (User.Read.All) and the user token authentication.
To ensure that we don't cross any throttling limits, we would like to know what is the RPS rate allowed per tenant for calls made by the Power BI app:

1. To usageRights API
2. Overall Graph APIs

Who can we contact to get this information?

Thank you,

Senior Software Developer in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [MS Graph throttling limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) documentation for information.